# Apollo Client strips away additional results from response object

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

We have implemented our graphql api *response* like this.

```
{
  data:  {...},
  skip: 0,
  limit: 10,
  total: 100,
  hasMore: true
}
```

If I query our api via graphiql the response looks like expected.
But unfortunately the apollo client in our application strips away all properties from the return object except `data`.

Is this expected behaviour?
And if so, how can I change it or solve this problem differently.
I need to get the total amount of data to implement pagination accordingly.

I know there is a method with `fetchMore` but it won't tell me the whole amount of entries in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Response-Format) only three top-level keys are expected -- `data`, `errors` and `extensions`. If you include additional keys you're going off-spec -- I would not expect any client to attempt to read them.

At the end of the day, this information should be included in your schema and returned as part of the `data` in the response. Returning it anywhere else (as additional keys in the response, as response headers, etc.) is a bad idea, if for no other reason than the fact that you could have multiple query fields at the root level, in which case you'd only be able to convey pagination information about one of the fields and it'd be unclear which field the information applied to. The same could be said if you have nested fields that can also be paginated.

Comment: Thanks, but I will have to implement this for a lot of endpoints. Isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: That depends on what your hangup is.